# mule dataweave conditional check loop

Tags: loops, conditional-statements, dataweave

I have a requirement to do the below

1) extract the addressline4 and concatenate with Addressline1 if addressline4 is present
2) extract addressline3 and concatenate with Addressline1 if addressline4 is not  present and addressline3 is present
3) extract addressline2 and concatenate with Addressline1 if addressline4 is not  present, if addressline3 is not  present and addressline2 is present
4) extract only Addressline1 is the rest are all empty

I have tried something as below but doesn't seem to work, highly appreciate any help on this. Also I need to restrict the charaters for street to 40 :

street: flowVars.addressLine1 ++ ' ' ++ flowVars.addressLine4 when flowVars.addressLine4 !='' otherwise flowVars.addressLine1 ++ ' ' ++ flowVars.addressLine3 when flowVars.addressLine3 !='' otherwise flowVars.addressLine1 ++ ' ' ++ flowVars.addressLine2 when flowVars.addressLine2 !='' otherwise flowVars.addressLine1

Answer (score 0):

I think your ordering is just off.

Try this:

```
t: flowVars.addressLine1 ++ ' ' ++ flowVars.addressLine2 when flowVars.addressLine2 !='' otherwise flowVars.addressLine1 ++ ' ' ++ flowVars.addressLine3 when flowVars.addressLine3 !='' otherwise flowVars.addressLine1 ++ ' ' ++ flowVars.addressLine4 when flowVars.addressLine4 !='' otherwise flowVars.addressLine1
```